# What do they use in place of actual marijuana plants?

Tags: props, trailer-park-boys

We see a lot of weed plants in Trailer Park Boys, they look very very real.

What are these plants?

Is there a standard showbiz weed plant look-a-like?

[image]

Comment: It wasn't weed; http://www.reddit.com/r/trailerparkboys/comments/vnm84/i_am_bernard_aka_cyrus_robichaud_from_the_trailer/

Comment: As for a 'weed' look alike: Hemp. Which is essentially weed, albeit minus the THC--and is completely legal in Canada.

Comment: I have always thought that they used plastic plants...

Comment: @mattiav27 that's what I thought as well, but you see them lighting and smoking it in a few scenes so I'm guessing it has to be something natural.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found [this page](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/tv-movies/smoking-scenes-call-pot-cocaine-hollywood-turns-stash-faux-drugs-article-1.427128) on New York Daily, from the title:

> What are they smoking?! When scenes call for pot or cocaine, Hollywood
>   turns to stash of faux drugs

later it says:

> Turns out that many cocaine look-alikes are ingredients you might use
>   in a cake, like powdered sugar, powdered milk and baking soda, while
>   herbal tobacco fills in for genuine cannabis. [...] When faux pot plants are 
>   needed, as they were in "Weeds," things got costly.
>
> “In seasons two and three, we were growing hydroponically indoors,”
>   Benabib says. “We needed literally hundreds of the plants, and they
>   are very expensive. They cost an arm and a leg.”

Of course there are also exceptions like *Easy Rider*: according to IMDB in this movie they were smoking actual marijuana.

**EDIT**

There is also [this article](http://flavorwire.com/489226/how-do-you-film-characters-smoking-weed-the-makers-of-high-maintenance-weeds-and-getting-doug-with-high-explain): this explains that

> Since "Weeds" also involved a fair amount of growing, not just selling,
>   the art department also had to supply “plants.” Entire grow houses
>   were outfitted with **plastic plants** — like the fake flower you might
>   use to spruce up your cubicle, except weed, and lots of it. A
>   late-series episode that finds Nancy Botwin’s onetime supplier growing
>   in Humboldt required planting nearly a hundred plastic plants in the
>   ground. **The effect is strikingly realistic, except for the fact that
>   actors couldn’t prune plastic: “If you look close when they’re
>   trimming ’em, they’re not really doing much.”**

(bold font is mine).

Comment: But wait, what's the faux plant? You haven't mentioned its name.

Comment: @Walt explanation added

Comment: Oh, an actual *fake plant*, I see. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Places like [ISS](https://issprops.com/props/) or [RJR Props](http://www.rjrprops.com/drugs--props-.html) (USA) and [SugaVision](http://sugavision.com/sugavision/gallery.html) (UK) made realistic movie props for use in industry and not for sale to the general public. See also this article in [Vice.com](https://www.vice.com/en_ca/article/vdx59a/how-do-they-make-drugs-look-real-in-films-prop-master-alcohol-cigarettes).

The props for Weeds were managed by [Jode S. Mann](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0542817/) and created in their [art department](http://flavorwire.com/489226/how-do-you-film-characters-smoking-weed-the-makers-of-high-maintenance-weeds-and-getting-doug-with-high-explain).

[image: RJR Props Marijuana]

[image: SugaVision]

SugaVision also offers industrial hemp, which of course will look identical.

---

Plants that look like Marijuana:

- [Japanese Maple](https://brusselsbonsai.com/japanese-maple-bonsai-tree-dt8023jmsp/)

[image: Japanese Maple]

- [Hibiscus acetosella](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/all/hibiscus-acetosella/)

[image: Hibiscus Acetosella]

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't answer what this particular film/show (unsure which) used.